# get session value from asp.net to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, session

I am creating a web app using asp.net and angularjs i am passing my session variable from c# to javascript as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pm = "<%= Convert.ToString(Session["mysession"]) %>";
    var log = "<%= Convert.ToString(Session["radio"]) %>";        
</script>
```

but i am getting error: `BC30203: Identifier expected.`

on: `Line 111:        var pm = "<%= Convert.ToString(Session["mysession"]) %>";`

what could be the possible reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, the output of `Session["mysession"]` contains a quote and is prematurely ending your expression, creating invalid syntax after the inner quote.

If you know there will be no single-quotes, switch to that (below), otherwise, escape the quote when setting `Session["mysession"]` on the server side.

```
var pm = '<%= Convert.ToString(Session["mysession"]) %>';
```